# How can I calculate the number of bytes in the packet payload?

Tags: c, sockets

There is a client and a server, at application layer, a client is sending packets to server of random payload sizes. That means one packet can be of 1300 bytes, next packet can be of 450 bytes, and next packet can be of 1449 bytes and so on. At server how you can read payload data incoming from clients ? How much data your socket should read ? considering the fact that client can not send the payload size it is sending. How can server differentiate between individual packets of 1300, 450 and 1449 bytes. We are using POSIX sockets in C and working at application layer. Any code snippet will be helpful.

Comment: What protocol are you using?  I.e. what are the arguments to the `socket ` call?

Comment: `Any code snippet will be helpful` Yes, exactly, that would help us understand your problem ;-) Seriously, please edit question so it fits here.

Comment: Is this for TCP or UDP? I'm assuming TCP, considering that "*client can not send the payload size it is sending*" would not be a problem on UDP, only TCP. Why is the client not able to send a payload size? In TCP, unless the sender sends a payload size or a unique message delimiter, there is no way to differentiate message boundaries. What do the message payloads actually look like?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

In general, you simply issue a [`recv()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/recv.2.html) with a buffer large enough to hold the largest datagram you expect. The return value will reflect the actual size of the datagram.

POSIX does not specify a way to check the size of the next datagram (other than reading it).

However, Linux and BSD systems do, for some protocols; for others, it will return the number of already received bytes available for reading. If you are using for example an [UDP socket](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/udp.7.html), then you can use the `FIONREAD` [`ioctl()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl.2.html). Here's an example:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

size_t unread(const int socketfd)
{
    int length = 0;
    if (ioctl(socketfd, FIONREAD, &length))
        return 0;
    if (length < 0)
        return 0;
     return (size_t)length;
}
```

Of course, this will not really tell you whether there is received data pending. For one, it might have arrived just after the `ioctl()`. Also, it is possible to send zero-length datagrams. The above function will return zero on both (no datagram received, and zero-length datagram received), as well as on errors (socket protocol does not support the ioctl).